# IF statement with multiple ifs and multiple worksheet returns

Tags: excel, excel-2013, excel-indirect

I have designed an Excel 'Master' worksheet with continuous months on separate W/S behind it (ie Master, jul2013, aug2013, etc.). I would like to insert an IF statement that does the following:

from cell E2 in Master look in 'Master' B2
if B2 = say 'aug2013'
then go to worksheet 'aug2013' and brings back contents of 'cell B102'.

On the master sheet, this would need to be repeated in next cell down (i.e. E3 checks B3, goes to corresponding sheet, and retrieves cell B102).

I have tried multiple if statements but am not having much luck.

Would VBA help?

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

(Sometimes it helps if you include the examples of what you have tried - it gives insight to your thinking and can make it easier to point out what is going wrong.)

I made the following example:
1 x Worksheet - Master
2 x Worksheets (Jul2013 & Aug2013)

On the master worksheet, make sure you've entered the value as text (use an apostrophe (') before the value) otherwise Excel thinks it is a date.

The formula in E2 is:

```
=IF(B2="Jun2013",'Jun2013'!B102,IF(B2="Jul2013",'Jul2013'!B102,IF(B2="Aug2013",'Aug2013'!B103,"Can't find it")))
```

Copy and paste it for th remaining rows.

- Cell E2 shows you what is in 'Aug2013'!B103
- Cell E3 is what happens if the reference cell (B3) is a date
- Cell E4 is an example of what happens if you reference a worksheet that doesn't exist

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and based on Excel 2007, because it is always B102 that is required:

```
=INDIRECT(B2&"!B102")
```

should serve (copied down to suit).

As mentioned by @ChristianPayne, this requires that B2 etc are formatted as text (since worksheet names are strings!)

[INDIRECT](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/indirect-function-HA102752975.aspx).

Comment: =INDIRECT("'"&B2&"'!B102")

Comment: oops, i ended up using this pnuts  thanks also & @chrispayne.  trying attach screen shot for you both